# no hidapi-jni in java.library.path

Tags: java, netbeans

Setting up a dll to my path. I've already created the dll. I need to put the dll in the path thou :p It's a java program running in netbeans if that helps. Please excuse the noobness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put it in the current working directory it should load. When you're running in netbeans, this is the top level netbeans project directory.